# Automatically replace all dead link texts in an HTML-page

Tags: html, regex, shell, curl, automation

I have a daily dynamically created firmware-download page with lots of different download links: https://freifunk.in-kiel.de/firmware/release-candidate/2018.1~exp-215/site/download/

Now not every day all those downloads are valid, but there should still be a note then, that those firmwares are n/a.

I thought about parsing the script via a regular expression to get all links on that page and then start some curl call, that checks if the link is dead or not. If dead, then replace the text of the link with "n/a".

Comment: You have an approach to follow. Where in it did you stuck?

Comment: Your approach is not that bad imo. Get the links via a simple expression like [**`https?://\S+`**](https://regex101.com/r/MpQEvc/1/) and test them with i.e. curl. I'd favor some kind of programming language like `Python` though.

Comment: You say your page is dynamically created, can't you modify this creation script to check links before putting them in the page?  Otherwise, to speed it up, you could 1) change language.  Perl (example, you can use what you want) is *much* faster than shell.  2) put a rather small timeout on your `wget` command.  The longer you wait on dead pages, the longer your script takes.

Comment: its not possible to create the page without those links, the creation is another server where I created the template, this template cannot be regenerated all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script successfully checks all links containing the string "gluon":

```
#!/bin/bash
# set the new version here
CUR=2018.1~ngly-234
BRANCH='nightly'
OUT_FILE=index.html
wget -k --no-check-certificate http://freifunk.in-kiel.de/firmware-rc.html -O $OUT_FILE
# replace the data from the template
sed -i 's|/sysupgrade/gluon-ffki-<VERSION>|/sysupgrade/gluon-ffki-'$CUR'|g' $OUT_FILE
sed -i 's|/factory/gluon-ffki-<VERSION>|/factory/gluon-ffki-'$CUR'|g' $OUT_FILE
sed -i 's|release-candidate|'$BRANCH'/'$CUR'|g' $OUT_FILE
echo -n "dead link check "
#sed -i "s/tube2/nixtube2/g" $OUT_FILE  # for debug to create a dead link
INVALID='">n/a </a><deadlink none="'
while IFS= read -r URL; do
  if wget --no-check-certificate --spider "$URL" 2>/dev/null; then
    echo -n .
  else
    echo
    echo "$URL does not exist"
    sed -i 's|'$URL'|'$URL''"$INVALID"'|g' $OUT_FILE
  fi
#done < <(grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*' $OUT_FILE|grep gluon|grep alfa)  # for debug
done < <(grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*' $OUT_FILE|grep gluon)
echo "dead link check done"
sed -i 's|http://|//|g' $OUT_FILE
```